# Updating list when it should be clearing it

Tags: android

I am currently working on inviting clients as guests to use my app. The invitation will be sent by email and their email address will appear in a RecyclerView until they have accepted it. I have made a clear button which will clear all emails within the ListView but for some reason once I selected the clear button, it clears the emails okay, but if I go to input a new email, then all emails previously in the list appear again.

Here is the code used.

```
public class InviteAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<InviteAdapter.UserViewHolder> {
    private static final String TAG = "Invite";

    private List <Invites> invites;

    public InviteAdapter(List<Invites> invites){
        this.invites = invites;
    }

    @Override
    public UserViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        final View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.row_email_invite, parent, false);

        return new UserViewHolder(itemView);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(UserViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Invites invite = invites.get(position);

        holder.emailAddress.setText(invite.getEmail_address());
    }

    Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return invites.size();
    }

    public class UserViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView emailAddress;

        public UserViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            emailAddress = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.row_email);
        }
    }

    public void setInvites(List<Invites> invites){
        this.invites = invites;
        notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    public void delete() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Invites deleted");
        invites.clear();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Also have put an image of how the client invite XML looks:

[image]

Comment: you have to clear that data source too from where you are building your list

Comment: Can you please elaborate on that please?

Comment: like if you are getting data from database then if only clear your list then data in database still remains there and next you are going to make your list all that data will come again

Comment: Ah okay, i get what you mean now. How would incorporate clearing the data in the database? thanks

Comment: in database case you can run the delete query to delete records

Comment: yes thank you thats brilliant! working fine now

Comment: I wil add that as an answer then

Comment: yeah i had added code to delete all records in database using DbManager, and seems to be working fine, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only **clearing your list** will not help you get rid of the data as data of your list **still exists in your original data source** and when you will fetch data from that source again you will get the data you removed from the list. To get rid of that also remove data from your source also.

**For eg.** If you are creating your **list from database** then when you clear your list also **delete all records from your database**  too using delete query.